# Absolutely positioned child overflow parents borders

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have an absolutely positioned (child) element in a relative (parent) container. I want the absolutely positioned element to span the entire width of its container, including padding and borders.

The border/padding may be different sizes, so I do not want to hardcode an offset.

Is such a thing possible?

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>


ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle outlining the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/du0yhawm/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Without manual adjustments it is not possible to have a child element cover the borders of its parent element. Even with `box-sizing: border-box` on the parent, `position: absolute` elements only fill from inside the border. `top: 0` will always reference the topmost pixel before the border.

You'll need to adjust manually if you want to make this happen. [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) can help, but you might want to look at the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) first.

http://jsbin.com/qusita/1/edit?html,css,output

```css
.out {
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  background-color: #555;
  
  border: 3px solid #aaa;
}

.in {
  top: 0;
  left: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: 100%;
  
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in"></div>
</div>
```

As a side note, `ul` & `ol` elements usually have some amount of default margin / padding, so look out for that.

---

Here's an alternative using more robust markup. Generally speaking there are many ways to achieve similar appearances in CSS, sometimes you need to think outside the box (model) a little.

http://jsbin.com/taluko/1/edit?html,css,output

```css
.one {
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  background-color: #777;
}

.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.three {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top: 5px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a height of your parent you just need to add `top: 0`  and `bottom: 0`. In this case child will be positioned in your parent container without paddings.

But in your case it won't work because of absolute positioned child parent will be empty and will have height is 0 plus paddings.

As a variant see the fiddle with updated example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5gtppy4x/1/

I've just added `top`, `bottom` for child and `height` for parent.

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was to just add to the parent:

```css
overflow: hidden;
```